# merging streams in rust / tokio

Tags: rust, stream, rust-tokio

`tokio` has a [Merge](https://docs.rs/crate/tokio/0.2.17/source/src/stream/merge.rs) data structure which allows to "merge" two homogeneous streams and forget the provenance.

```
impl<T, U> Stream for Merge<T, U> where
    T: Stream,
    U: Stream<Item = T::Item>, { ...
```

Is there an algebraic pointwise tagged union for streams, which from a stream of `a` and a stream of `b`, produces a stream of `Either a b` ?

PS : I guess the answer is *no* as there is no standard sum type in rust apparently..

Comment: But you can easily define your own `Either` then map both streams to Streams to `Either` and merge them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's provided directly as a method in tokio, but you piece it together very simply yourself. There is no `Either` type in the Rust standard library but, like most other things, there's [a crate](https://crates.io/crates/either) for that.

```
use either::Either; // 0.3.7
use tokio::stream::StreamExt as _;

stream1
    .map(Either::Left)
    .merge(stream2.map(Either::Right))
```

Comment: It seems to be the easiest way. the crate approach puts the end user in the front seat (and limits library author)